# DCRoundSwitch gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, exc-bad-access, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using [`DCRoundSwitch`](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch) for a project where I basically need an `UISwitch` where I'm able to edit its label contents.

Because I'm using `ARC` I refactored the `DCRoundSwitch` code to be `ARC`-compatible in xcode.

When compiling and running in the simulator it works without any problems.

However, when running on the device it gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` near line 57 of `DCRoundSwitchKnobLayer.m`

There is a [bug report](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch/issues/10) at GitHub but no solution has been found yet.

Here is the code that gives `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`:

```
CGGradientRef CreateGradientRefWithColors(CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef endColor)
{
    CGFloat colorStops[2] = {0.0, 1.0};
    CGColorRef colors[] = {startColor, endColor};

    //THIS LINE BREAKS THE PROGRAM
    CFArrayRef colorsArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void**)colors, sizeof(colors) / sizeof(CGColorRef), &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks); 

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colorsArray, colorStops);
    CFRelease(colorsArray);
    return gradient;
}
```

Any clues would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here are the local variables from xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colorsArray` is released using the method `CFRelease`. ARC doesn't allow the use of `retain` and `release`, so why don't you try commenting the line `CFRelease(colorsArray)` and see if that prevents the error?

Edit--

This answer was accepted as it supplied a valid fix to the OP's issue, by disabling ARC.

If you do not want to use this method, please see @petesh's answer.

Comment: Can you upload your arc refactored code? Also, it may just be better to turn off arc for the individual files. I just tested it out and it works perfectly - http://cl.ly/3p0O0f3m1B1d0K1h0L3S

Comment: +1 because I solved it by turning off ARC for this individual file. Guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: Exact same problem here, turning off ARC with the compiler flag fixed it for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I really wanted to convert the code to ARC.
The crash occurs because startColor and endColor are already freed when CreateGradientRefWithColors is called.

Here is my fix:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor.CGColor, (__bridge id) endColor.CGColor, nil];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);
}
```

This post helped in finding the solution: http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/02/28/a-funny-thing-happened-on-the-way-to-the-arc/

Comment: There's just a little typo in the answer: the right function to call is GradientRefWithColors() and not CreateGradientRefWithColors(). That said THIS should be the right/accepted answer, 'cause it the only one that actually solve the problem...

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

Apologies, the correct fix for this code with ARC is:

```
CGGradientRef CreateGradientRefWithColors(CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef endColor)
{
    CGFloat colorStops[2] = {0.0, 1.0};
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)startColor, (id)endColor, nil];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, colorStops);

    return gradient;
}
```

You use a bridge conversion from an NSArray of the colors, rather than going to the extra work of creating the the CFArrayRef. This refactoring is shamelessly stolen from the Discussions on [Core Graphics 101](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients). Which is an awesome site of turorials on Objective-C.

The [Everything you wanted to know about ARC](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/) has a few guides about this. The [ARC Q&A](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) also has some good guides on this.

Comment: It gives: `Incompatible types casting 'CGColorRef [2]' to 'void **' with a __bridge cast`. However, I just found this: https://github.com/LordLobo/LLRoundSwitch I'm going to try it out.

Comment: It didn't help. It suffers from the same bug.

Comment: I use this solution but still get me Incompatible types casting 'CGColorRef' *'aka'struct CGColor to 'void' **' with a__bridge cast

Comment: Apologies, I left the incorrect answer at the bottom of the main answer, which exhibits the problem you mentioned. Please use the code at the start of the answer, rather than the broken remainder code.